# How to reboot an Acer B3-A20 into safe mode?

Tags: reboot, safe-mode

When holding down the Power off button on the screen, nothing happens till I let go, and then the system just powers off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide is not exactly for your model, but it will probably work on your model, too:

> Turn on safe mode
>
> 1. Turn device off.
> 2. Press power button.
> 3. When the "Acer" logo is displayed, release the power button.
> 4. Immediately after releasing the power buton, hold the volume down button.
> 5. Keep holding down the volume down button until the phone finishes rebooting.
> 6. Release the volume down button when you see `Safe Mode` appear in the lower left corner of the screen.

Source: http://howtosafemode.com/843/how-to-turn-on-safe-mode-on-acer-iconia-tab-7-a1-713?show=845#a845

Comment: @MarkYisri It is a guide for an Acer phone. But devices made by the same manufacturer are probably using the same key combinations